# Can I use something similar to <wbr> inside a plotly chart function?

Tags: html, r, shiny, plotly

How can I have a conditional break line inside a plotly chart?

Let's suppose is a pie chart and I have this data

| String | Num |
| --- | --- |
| First item | 10 |
| Second item | 15 |
| Enormous gigantic item | 20 |
| Fourth item | 7 |

How can I have a plotly pie chart that break the Enormous gigantic item into two or three lines depending of the plot's size? Can I have it in a different number of lines than the legend?
Like three lines inside the pie and one or two in the legend?

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to change your string variable before ploting.

For example, on this code we add breaks between words in all values from String column with more than 20 characters.

**Sample data:**

```
data <- data.frame(
  String = c("First item", "Second item", "Enormous gigantic item", "Fourth item"),
  Num = c(10, 15, 20, 7)
)
```

**Add line breaks to the "String" column if it has more than 20 characters**

```
data$String <- ifelse(nchar(data$String) > 20, gsub(" ", "<br>", data$String), data$String)
```

**Plot output:**

```
plot_ly(data, labels = ~String, values = ~Num, type = 'pie') %>%
  layout(title = 'Pie Chart with Multi-Line Labels')
```

[image]

Comment: That's a nice solution @Lucca Nielsen
But I was looking for a more flexible fix. Something that could break or not regarding the plots size.

You know, just like when the pie chart changes the inside label from horizontal do tangential if it's to small to accommodate the whole text?